# ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 530: Duplicate entry '20190617051131-apply-schema.js' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 530: Duplicate entry '20190617051131-apply-schema.js' for key 'PRIMARY' in importing database in mysql workbench

[image]

Comment: What's the question? Are you claiming there isn't a duplicate?

Comment: I want to know why the import is error.

Comment: As the error says you have a duplicate.

Comment: is that on the script of database columns ?